# Where to put the attributes of a relationship in a non many-to-many relationship?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Say that I have the following one-to-many relationship:

[image]

If I don't want to store any information about the relationship, I can simply put the primary key of `School` as foreign key in the `Student` table.

But let's say that I want to store the date on which a student has registered in a school. In this case, can I still put the primary key of `School` as foreign key in the `Student` table alongside the `date_of_registration` attribute? or should I create a new table that contains `school_id` and `student_id` as foreign keys alongside the `date_of_registration` attribute?

If I can use both either approach, what are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

Comment: `student has registered in a school` You already answered your self. `Register` seems a legit entity for me. Anyways, it depends whether you need to keep certain traceability between students and schools. Or students-schools-somethingElse

Answer (score 1):

According to your data model, each student has exactly one school. It makes sense from that point of view to put the relationship meta data on the student, as each student has exactly one of those, too. You can normalize that further to have a relationship table in between, but it is hard to imagine a use case that would necessitate it.

In fact, if it turns out you need more general-purpose data on the student then logically, you would have a 'person' model instead and the 'student' would be the 1-m relationship between person and school.

Comment: I agree with this.  While you could create a separate table, it would be a one-to-one relationship with `Student` anyway, and unless there are security concerns, there's no reason why a `Student` shouldn't also contain information relative to its relationship with `School`.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that creating a new/extra table would create extra data to store and extra processing when dealing with queries/updates. If a student can only register once for one school, if they switch school then the table is updated, but it is wholly dependent on the student, when they register at the school.

Answer (score 0):

Your Student entity type is the intersection between School and Person, a many-to-many relationship. As currently documented you have chosen to omit the history of registrations and hold only the current registration. As such Person -- student is 1-to-1 and it is OK to fold Person into Student as you have done. If your problem domain requires history separate Person (name, dob etc.) from Student (registration_date).